# 'None' mean in python

Tags: python, printing

I don't know why the code below and its output are coming out like this.
Thank you for your detailed explanation.

```
def outer():
    print('hi')

print(outer)
outer()
print(outer())
print(print('hi'))
```

> <function outer at 0x7f95c25ba160>
> hi
> hi
> None
> hi
> None

Comment: What, exactly do you not understand?

Comment: When printing the function print, you print None

Comment: `None` means `null`.

Answer (score 1):

"**None**" is a special Python value that holds a place when there is nothing return value. Also, It is not the same as the boolean value False. So, you should write it like this;

```
def outer():
    return 'hi'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put a `return` statement in a Python function, the default return value is `None`.  Your function `outer` just prints and returns `None`.  Calling `print(outer())` prints the return value of `outer()` which is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

`print(outer)`
The name of a function is a reference to its location in memory, so printing it out will result in the location of the function in memory.

`outer()`
Calling the function activates the code inside, `print('hi')`, so 'hi' will be printed.

`print(outer())`
Here the function will be activated to evaluate what should be printed, so 'hi' is printed, and then None (No return).

`print(print('hi'))`
Same goes here as above, 'hi' is printed and then None.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [python language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html)

> (a function that returns no meaningful result; in Python, procedures return the value None).

So any function that does not explicitly return a value will return `None`.

Why so? I think this is mostly to provide a always false value. If you forgot to return but also assign the return value to a variable to make a choice later on
then having it be a "thruthy" value be problematic! You might assume some work is done but it never happened and leads you to a **logical** bug instead of a coding bug!

```py
def foo():
     print("foo")
     # here I forget to return True and now the function will return None

if foo():
     # never taken now but I'm assuming it will
else:
     # will land here
```

This might be confusing to beginners but later on when you will
construct more complex code and will compose more function it's
gonna come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

When you are telling python to print() something, it will either put a string into the console, OR do it's best to try represent the data you gave it. In this case, the following happens with each call:

`print(outer)` -> This is telling python to print the function object 'outer'. Python handles this by printing where in the computer's memory `outer()` is being stored as hexadecimal. If you aren't familiar with hexadecimal, it is base 16 and you can read about it [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/hexadecimals.html).

`outer()` -> This is telling python to run the function `outer()`, so it just runs the print function that you have inside it.

`print(outer())` -> This tells python to print the output of `outer()`. Since you don't have a `return` statement, nothing is returned. Thus, python just gives None as the return value. You will notice it still prints 'hi' because in order to get to the where a return might be, python has to run all the code inside of `outer()`, including `print('hi')`.

`print(print('hi'))'' -> Much like calling` print(outer())`, you are telling python to print the return of the function` print()`, which will just return None as` print()`` does not return anything. Just like with the aforementioned example, the code inside the print statement is run while trying to find a return, so the 'hi' is printed by the inner print before the None is by the outer print.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you write a function , you need a "return" keyword to print or return the values from the function.

rather write your code as :

```
def outer():
    return "hi"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get an output of `None` when you do `print(print("hi"))` is because essentially a print statement [`print()`] is considered to be `None type`.

What I suggest you to do is:

- Change your `print("hi")` to `return "hi"` so that you can call the `outer()` function using `print(outer())`. This is also useful because you can store your function in a variable: `say_hi = outer()`, and will be able to print it whenever you want, e.g. `print(say_hi)`